# Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core assembly not found

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, msbuild-task

[image: Visual representation of the issue.]

Basically, I'm trying to create an MSBuild Task by inheriting from Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.task.aspx) for Microsoft's documentation on the class. The error shown is that the Utilities name doesn't exist in the Microsoft.Build namespace.

I know in the image I'm trying to reference Microsoft.Build.Utilties.Core but this was just due to troubleshooting. Utilities is not found. You can see on the right in the image that I've got a reference to Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, which I recently installed from Nuget. I've also tried the Visual Studio Installer, checking the box for developing Visual Studio Extensions. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

And as it turns out, I had managed to confuse my project names. The project I had added the reference to is not the same as the project this file is in. Oops.